# How to implement delegates that are safe for async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a `Subscriber.cs` that accepts an action, listens to a RabbitMQ-queue, and performs said action on any message from that queue:

```
public class Subscriber {

     public Subscriber(Action<T> consumeMessage)
            {
                _consumeMessage = consumeMessage;
            }

            ....

            void HandleMessage(T message) {
                    try
                    {
                          _consumeMessage(message);                          
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {                 
                        _logger.LogError("Some error message");
                    }
            }
    }
```

This worked fine, until I (accidentally) provided an async function:

```
 var subscriber = new Subscriber<MyMessage>(
                consumeMessage: message =>
                {
                    messageHandler.HandleAsync(message);
                });
```

This executes the action in a 'fire and forget' fashion, which still works when it works, but fails silently when it fails.

So I tried this:

```
   var subscriber = new Subscriber<MyMessage>(
                    async consumeMessage: message =>
                    {
                        await messageHandler.HandleAsync(message);
                    });
```

This of course looks pretty, but somehow causes the exception to occur in this snippet (rather than inside `Subscriber`) causing the whole app to crash.

So I tried this:

```
   var subscriber = new Subscriber<MyMessage>(
                    consumeMessage: message =>
                    {
                        messageHandler.HandleAsync(message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    });
```

This works as intended, but might lead to a deadlock (if I am to believe the internet).

It also makes my `Subscriber` a very unfriendly and dangerous-to-use component as it the two first examples both compile even though they don't actually work.

How should I design my `Subscriber` component so that it can work with async delegates safely?

Comment: Why not catch the exception inside HandleAsync so that it does not propagate?

Comment: Because the Subscriber resides in a shared library for our organization, so it would be nice to have that stuff already taken care of for everyone using the library

Comment: Create new subscriber which accepts async `Func<T, Task>` delegate (or add another constructor which accepts it) and handle it appropriately.

Comment: If you change subscriber to take a `Func<Task, T>` then you can await the delegate in HandleMessage.

Comment: There is not enough context here to know what the right answer in your case is. For starters, if you want only readers who are already familiar with RabbitMQ, you need to tag your question appropriately. Otherwise, you need to show a good [mcve] that completely illustrates how your `Subscriber` class works. Beyond that, the fact is that, while yes, waiting synchronously on an async operation _might_ lead to deadlock, whether that's actually the case depends on how your `HandleMessage()` method is called and on what might be in the async code. You haven't shared any of those details with us.

Comment: The bottom line here: given the declarations you've shown here, you have only two choices: risk deadlock, or let the exception happen after the `HandleMessage()` method has returned and deal with that exception in some other way. If you can change the declarations, i.e. as suggested in previous comments, then you can make a `HandleMessageAsync()`; ideally, this will work in conjunction with a constructor overload that accepts `Func<T, Task>` (even the code you posted isn't valid, because `T` is undefined and `HandleMessage()` has its parameter typed as `object`, not `T`).

Comment: You first version is actually a good practice. Subscribe as an infrastructure class should not handle business logic errors. As long as it delivers the message to the action, it's job is done. In terms of error handling, you have two choices. First is to have each action handles it own error. Your first version of subscriber is fine for this case. The second choice is to have whoever send the message handles the error. This would require the Subscriber to return a Task to the message sender. And the sender should await Task. The signature of HandleMessage need to change to return Task

Comment: Thanks for good comments everyone! I resolved to providing an overload that takes a Func<T, Task> and handling everything async in the Subscriber. To those of you who suggested this I will happily accept if you post it as an answer :)